# How can show 4 poduct in row express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to display the 4 product in row but i don't know. How can i do?, because it show the one product in row. I want show the medicine detail below the pic but it show details right side of pic

Route.js

```
router.get('/allMedicine', (req, res)=>{
   Medicine.find()
     .then(medicines=>{
        res.render('allMedicine',{
            medicine: medicines
        })
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Ejs

```
<head>
   <title>All Medicine</title>
   <link href="/stylesheets/medicine.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <% for (let i =0; i<medicine.length; i++){%>
      <td>
        <img id="pic" src="./medicine/<%= medicine[i].medicinePic%>" alt="pic"><br>
      </td>
      <td> <%= medicine[i].name%></td>
      <td><%= medicine[i].price%></td>
      <td> <%= medicine[i].power%></td>
      <td><%= medicine[i].quantity%></td>
    </tr>
    <%}%>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Electron, however I think I can answer in plain HTML which will get the point across.

#### Your method

Here you have all the information on one row of the table. As such they all appear, in order, next to each other.

```html
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <!-- First Row -->
  <tr>
    <td> Image should go Here</td>
    <td>
      This item is below the image
    </td>
    <td>
      This item is below the image 2
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

#### Suggestion

Here I have placed the information about the product in a new row. This will allow the info to appear below.

```html
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<table>
<!-- First Row -->
  <tr>
    <td> Image should go Here</td>
  </tr>
  
  <!-- Second Row -->
  <tr>
    <td>
      This item is below the image
    </td>
    <td>
      This item is below the image 2
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

However this will leave you with essentially two rows per product. I only did this based on your current use of a `<td>` for each bit of product info. Instead I think you should just have all the info for each product, including the image, in one `<td>` and then use some css to make the text formatted how you would like.

```html
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  .info p {
    float: left;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="your image" alt="Image Here" />
      <div class="info">
        <p>Name </p>
        <p>Quantity</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="your image" alt="image here" />
      <div class="info">
        <p>Name </p>
        <p>Quantity</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: do you have any idea how can i show 4 product in row ?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Css styles can be used to do that. Please see The updated answer, which places the text into a div and then uses styling to float the text to the left

Comment: but how can css put the 4 product in row ?

Comment: oh I see, sorry. Just stick each product into a new `<td>` instead of a new row.
However I really don't recommend using tables to achieve this.

For future, do some research into **FlexBox***